# Are there any guidelines for setting innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, performance, performance-tuning

The default value (20) seems to produce fairly accurate index cardinalities for small tables, which in turn results into good execution plans. But from what I've seen, accuracy starts falling off once your table grows.

It sounds reasonable, at least in my mind, that the number of pages to sample should be a percentage of the total number of rows.

I tried reading the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html) and also tried searching for related literature, but so far I haven't found anything.

I could always go the trial and error route, but surely I'm not the only one with this conundrum.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a crap shoot.

- Too high --> takes too long; and not necessarily better stats
- Too low --> inaccurate stats
- Percentage --> 1% is close to hitting every block (for the typical table that has about 100 rows per block).
- As table grows, InnoDB allegedly re-ANALYZEs after 10% growth, so no manual action needed.
- *Most* tables have decent stats from 20.
- Tables with uneven distribution won't benefit from changing the '20', at least not until some decent "histogram" stats are implemented.  Then, Optimization becomes much more complex, and potentially slower.

Bottom line:  Leave it at 20.  Keep the slowlog on.  Tackle the worst entry in the slowlog, with an eye for solutions that don't depend on the '20'.

Comment: Just for additional context, the reason why I decided to tweak it in the first place, was because when I upgraded one of the db hosts to 5.6, there was an increase in the number of slow queries. When I ran explain, that's when I noticed that some of the slow queries were using bad plans.

Comment: There were a number of significant changes to the Optimizer with 5.6.  Unfortunately, a few of the changes made things slower in a few cases.  Changing the "20" is very unlikely to be the "fix".  If you would like, let's discuss a specific query, its `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There may be a way to workaround the performance regression.

Comment: Fair enough, for this particular case though, I'm almost sure, that was caused by inaccurate statistics. The cardinality for one of the indexes wasn't supposed to be that high, and it was making the optimizer prioritize that index over the correct one. The table had ~50m rows, so what I did was I started  ramping up the value of  STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES for that specific table, ran analyze, and then ran explain again.

Comment: Hmmm... Perhaps the table is being inserted at then 'end', and the queries that use the wrong index touch mostly the 'end'?  Or some other pattern?  Can you elaborate on the inserts and the query.